# Python, matplotlib color gradient using imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I found a nice (working) example for a color gradient shadow a line chart (https://pradhanphy.blogspot.com/2014/06/filling-between-curves-with-color.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

xx=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
yy=xx*np.exp(-xx)

path = Path(np.array([xx,yy]).transpose())
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none')
plt.gca().add_patch(patch)

im = plt.imshow(xx.reshape(yy.size,1),  cmap=plt.cm.Reds,interpolation="bicubic",
                origin='lower',extent=[0,10,-0.0,0.40],aspect="auto", clip_path=patch, clip_on=True)
plt.show()
```

I've tried (without success) to adapt that example in order to use discrete x,y time series values as input data.

```
xx = np.array('2015-12-23 12:00:00',dtype='datetime64[ns]') 
xx = np.insert(xx, 0, ('2015-12-24 00:00:00'))
xx = np.insert(xx, 0, ('2015-12-25 00:00:00'))
yy = np.array([1,2,5])
```

I would be happy if somebody provides an idea.

Comment: The vertices in a mathplotlib Path must be floating point numbers.  You can't use date/time values.  I suppose you could convert them to day ordinals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.@TimRoberts. You are right: I can translate numpy datetime values in numeric values using a loop over all entries eg. with ``array_element.astype("float"))``. However, also the resulting chart is unable to show human readable dates because the x values are used as labels.